# Very slow segmentation using Python

Tags: gdal, geopandas, performance, rasterio, polygonize

I used both Python and QGIS to perform polygonization of a raster but the waiting times with Python are very long, while with QGIS the operation is done in a few seconds.

Could you tell me the reason of such difference?

This is my code:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.features import shapes
import geopandas as gpd

mask = None

with rasterio.open('...\\.tif') as src:
    image = src.read(1)
    results = (
    {'properties': {'DN': v}, 'geometry': s}
    for i, (s, v) 
    in enumerate(
        shapes(image, mask=mask, transform=src.transform)))

geoms = list(results)
gpd_polygonized_raster = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geoms,crs=src.crs.to_dict())
ss = gpd_polygonized_raster[gpd_polygonized_raster['DN']]
ss.to_file(...)
```

I also tried using GDAL, but it still takes much longer than QGIS.

Comment: What GDAL version? There are recent improvements in GDAL that makes building of complex multipolygons much faster.

Comment: Thanks, I had version 3.1 and upgrading to 3.2.2 has improved the situation.